# How can we group SQL once it is grouped in inner query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here i have one table for purchase.

```
| Invoice No | Customer |  Amount | Invoice Date(mm-dd-yy) |
|        101 | ABC      |    1000 |            01-01-2020  |
|        102 | XYZ      |    1000 |            01-01-2020  |
|        103 | ABC      |    1000 |            02-01-2020  |
|        104 | XYZ      |    1000 |            03-01-2020  |
|        105 | PQR      |    1000 |            01-01-2020  |
|        106 | ABC      |    1000 |            03-01-2020  |
```

Now I have to make Customer wise report.
so grouping will be on Customer which will be like this.

```
$sql->group(customer);
```

So after this table will generate like below..

```
| Invoice No | Customer | Amount | Invoice Date(mm-dd-yy) |
| 106        | ABC      |   3000 |             03-01-2020 |
| 104        | XYZ      |   2000 |             03-01-2020 |
| 105        | PQR      |   1000 |             01-01-2020 |
```

I also have to make summary for this as like.

```
| Invoice Amount | Total Count |
|           5000 |           5 |
```

**above all things are done, but the problem is i also have to generate Date Wise summary**

So how i get Date Wise summary?

```
    SELECT
   `t`.*,
   FORMAT(SUM(COALESCE(t.Total_Purchase_Amount_fororder, 0.00)), 2) AS Total_Purchase_Amount 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         `invoice_item`.*,
         `sr`.*,
         cust_comp.name AS cust_name,
         cust_comp.id AS cust_id,
         MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice.date, '%Y')) AS `Transaction_Year`,
         MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice.date, '%m')) AS `Transaction_Month`,
         MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice.date, '%m-%Y')) AS `Transaction_Month_Year`,
         FORMAT(COALESCE(COUNT(invoice.to_type_id), 0.00), 2) AS `Total_Purchases`,
         COUNT(invoice.to_type_id) AS `Total_Purchases_forsummary`,
         FORMAT(COALESCE(SUM(invoice_item.amountAfterDiscount) - COALESCE(total_return, 0.00) , 0.00), 2) AS `Total_Purchase_Amount`,
         SUM(invoice_item.amountAfterDiscount) - COALESCE(total_return, 0.00) AS `Total_Purchase_Amount_fororder`,
         FORMAT(COALESCE(MAX(invoice_item.amountAfterDiscount) - COALESCE(total_return, 0.00) , 0.00), 2) AS `Max_Purchase_Amount` 
      FROM
         `invoice` 
         INNER JOIN
            `cust_comp` 
            ON cust_comp.id = invoice.to_type_id 
         INNER JOIN
            (
               SELECT
                  SUM(amountWithTax) AS `amountWithTax`,
                  SUM(amountAfterDiscount) AS `amountAfterDiscount`,
                  FORMAT(sum(tax_amount), 2) AS `tax_amount`,
                  `invoice_item`.`invoice_id`,
                  `invoice_item`.`invoice_item_inventory_id` 
               FROM
                  `invoice_item` 
               WHERE
                  (
                     invoice_item.item_status NOT IN
                     (
                        8
                     )
                  )
               GROUP BY
                  `invoice_item`.`invoice_id`
            )
            AS `invoice_item` 
            ON invoice_item.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id 
         LEFT JOIN
            (
               SELECT
                  `sr`.`sales_return_id`,
                  `sr`.`invoice_id` AS `return_invoice_id`,
                  SUM(COALESCE(return_amountAfterDiscount, 0.00)) AS total_return,
                  `sri`.* 
               FROM
                  `sales_return` AS `sr` 
                  INNER JOIN
                     (
                        SELECT
                           `sri`.`sales_return_id` AS `item_sales_return_id`,
                           COALESCE(amountAfterDiscount, 0.00) AS `return_amountAfterDiscount` 
                        FROM
                           `sales_return_item` AS `sri`
                     )
                     AS `sri` 
                     ON sri.item_sales_return_id = sr.sales_return_id 
               WHERE
                  (
                     sr.invoice_id = invoice_id
                  )
               GROUP BY
                  `sr`.`invoice_id`
            )
            AS `sr` 
            ON sr.return_invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id 
      WHERE
         (
            invoice.invoice_status NOT IN
            (
               8,
               6
            )
         )
         AND 
         (
            invoice.date >= 1596240000
         )
      GROUP BY
         `invoice`.`to_type_id`
   )
   AS `t`
```

Expected Result for date wise summary is:

```
| Invoice Amount| Total Count | Invoice Date |
|          3000 |           3 |   01-01-2020 |
|          1000 |           1 |   02-01-2020 |
|          2000 |           2 |   03-01-2020 |
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Store dates using a date data type. Then see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thank you for letting us know. Can you please bit explain what does it mean? @Strawberry

Comment: Explain what???

Comment: i am not getting properly what you are saying about my question.

Comment: I can't use date data type so i am using the timestamp. @Strawberry

Comment: @BhumiParmar, Please share your date wise summary expected output.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . (1) I don't understand what your question is.  You seem to suggest three separate questions.  (2) You start your question by saying that you have one table, then you have a query that references multiple tables.  (3) You have a code sample using dataframes, but the question seems to be about SQL.  Confusing.

Comment: Actually the tables are just for example that which type i want to make the query and what will be the expected output, and the query is actual query in which i have to implement. @GordonLinoff

Comment: @AnkitBajpai i have updated my question for Expected result, please check it again.

Comment: @BhumiParmar . . . Your question is the only information anyone else has to help you.  Inconsistencies and lack of focus just make it much harder for anyone to help.

Comment: I think if the data were as simple as the first table you provide then the sql would be really simple but the sql statement you have shown us is very very complicate and references at least 5 different tables. I am sure there would be a much easier way to write your sql statement but without knowing the structure and sample data of all your tables I am not sure how I can help.